# RVM Ruby are not finding Gems despite showing the correct gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Used `rvm` to install a specific version of ruby, and then used `gem` to install a specific version of `nokogiri`

Every time I run my script however I get:

```
:1:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
```

Yet when I run `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2014-01-28 patchlevel 376) [i686-darwin15.6.0]
```

Or when I run `gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.4.2)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
nokogiri (1.4.7)
rake (10.1.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
```

And `which ruby`:

```
/Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby
```

And `which gem`:

```
/Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/gem
```

What am I missing? Why can't it find nokigiri even though it's in the gem list???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby 1.8 you need to require rubygems before you require other gems. e.g.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a gemset and install the gems for that specific ruby version

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics